# ASP.NET format string date

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I am connecting to a database, executing a query, and putting the data in a list. I have strings that have dates like so `mm/dd/yyyy hour:minute:second AM or PM` I am looking to format this data into yyyy-mm-dd with no time.

This is where I am assigning the data:

```
airportItems.ContractReceived_F = dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
```

how would I convert the `dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();` to the date format I want?

I have tried the following:

```
airportItems.ContractReceived_F = string.Format("{0:d}", dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString());
```

I am defining ContractReceived_F as string:

```
public string ContractReceived_F { get; set; }
```

and it still returned the time.

Comment: What about something like `.ToString("u")` ?

Comment: Great reference for string formatting: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
airportItems.ContractReceived_F = dataReader.GetDateTime(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

where yyyy represents the year, MM represents the month and dd represents the day.

Comment: This gives me an error No overload for method ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @user3922763 Updated with GetDateTime, since you're retrieveing DateTime object from db.

Answer (score 0):

why not parse the data you need to like this

```
DateTime unparsed_date = mydatevalue; //any date in any date format
string parsed_date = unparsed_date.toString("dd mm yyyy");
```

Theres an article on the different parses on msdn that i found for you 
[check it out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Credit goes to fubo for the link (thumbs up)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to  use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then you  choose the date format that you need

For example :

```
DateTime OutputDate = null;
DateTime.TryParseExact(DateFromTheView, "yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out OutputDate);
```

In the example : the format is "yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss tt" and the input date string is `DateFromTheView`. The `OutputDate` will take as value the new datetime object and if the instruction fails it will take null.